# OpenGL: Lots of small VBO's okay or not?

Tags: opengl, colors, vbo, vertex-buffer

I have a lot of objects but I want one of these objects (the one the mouse is hovering over) to "glow" (rapidly change colors).

So one way to do this is have each object have its own VBO. I will not have a color array. Then I will have like, a thousand VBO's each with about 20 quads... and if it's the selected object I will call glColor3f(blah,blah,blah) before it, else it will be the default color.

Another way is to have them all in one big VBO. I will have a color array. Then I will do something like, glBufferSubDataARB into the color array very frequently to make one object glow.

Which way is better and why? Also suggest another way if both ways are bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know something?  Just forget about the color array.  A color array makes no sense, because you don't have a different color per vertex, but for entire groups of objects.

Put all the vertex data into a single VBO, without any color data.

Then loop through the colors (or object groups), for each one you'll call `glColor3f` and `glDrawArrays`, where the `first` and `count` parameters match the number of vertices belonging to objects of that color.

When you move from the fixed-function pipeline to shaders someday, you'll just replace `glColor3f` by `glUniform3f`.

Comment: Thanks; this makes the most sense and makes me see how restricted my thinking was earlier

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the one bigger VBO. The reason is simple. If you had many VBOs you would have to be binding the buffer for each one before each draw call is issued.

EDIT: Also reading the reason you wanted to use multiple VBOs makes me wonder. Why not pass the color variables as uniform variable in a shader?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "uniform variables" or shader code; should I need to delve into shader code?

Comment: Then I have the perfect line of tutorials for you to follow. It will explain to you how to use the "modern" (ver 3.0++) openGL way.         http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Answer (score 0):

How many different colors?  Can you put them all into the VBO at once, and just use `glColorPointer` to select a different part of the VBO for the selected object for each frame?  Changing the offset into the VBO is more efficient than either binding a different buffer or uploading new data into the buffer.

Essentially I'm suggesting that you draw a bunch of normal unselected objects, then call `glColorPointer` to select the highlight color, then draw the selected object, then call `glColorPointer` to put the VBO offset back, then draw the remaining objects.

Just because all the vertex and color data is in a single VBO doesn't mean that you have to render all your objects with a single call.

Comment: Not sure if that will work since I want one object to glow and the other objects to be default color

Comment: @Peter: What draw function are you using, and how many objects are you drawing with a single call?

Comment: Ben's suggestion is the most optimal assuming you do have the space in your graphics memory. As he says if the number of objects you are drawing is not very big you can just have them duplicated in the VBO once with their color and once with the "glow" color and whenever issue a drawing call you just choose the appropriate VBO index to either the normal or the glow object.

Comment: How would it work? The suggestion seems to be to store colors as such: {red, green, blue, glow_red, glow_green, glow_blue, ...[repeat]}. Then when I do glColorPointer I can specify it to skip every 6 instead of every 3 values. But then how would I specify one of the objects to point to the second set? Moreover the "glow" color would still have to be rapidly changing. I am not quite understanding what you are saying

Comment: No,no you would have to interleave the Colors inside the VBO. Assume you have N object. So one object would be {x,y,z,r,g,b}  (simplistic ... you might also want normals and texture coords). Then you would have N of them in the VBO. Then you would add another N but with {x,y,z,_glow_r,_glow_g,_glow_b} in them. And then in your drawing code you would simply set the VBO index accordingly to either the N object if it is to be drawn with its color or the N+N object if you need to utilize the glow color.

There are other better ways to do it too but right now my mind is in no working-mode.

Comment: @Peter: no, I'm suggesting you store (`vertex1.x, vertex1.y, vertex1.r, vertex1.g, vertex1.b, ... vertexn.x, vertexn.y, vertexn.r, vertexn.g, vertexn.b, glowframe1_1.r, glowframe1_1.g, glowframe1_1.b` (repeated for however many vertices your most complex object has), `glowframe2_1.r, glowframe2_1.g, glowframe2_1.b`, ...).  You can change the color pointer offset and stride right before drawing the selected element, change it back right after.

Comment: @Lefteris: That is absolutely not what I'm suggesting.

Comment: So are you suggesting that instead of glDrawArrays once on the whole VBO, I split it up (even though it's still one big VBO)? something like, for all objects iterating int i, glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, i*numQuadsPerObject, numQuadsPerObject); then in between I can specify color pointer etc

Comment: @PeterJames: That's pretty much it.  See my newer answer.

Comment: @Ben yes I see, misinterpreted you answer totally. My bad